# Перенаправление пользователя с сохранением данных текущего запроса

Tags: java, jsp

Как сделать перенаправление пользователя при ответе сервлета с сохранением данных текущего запроса?

Я создал страницу index.html, в которой сделал форму для заполнения (логин, пароль). Данный через action form отправляются cервлету. Вопрос: Как мне перебросить пользователя на другую страницу html, при этом вставляя данные из переменных сервлета?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747618/redirect-from-servlet-to-servlet

Answer (score 0):

У `HttpServletRequest` есть метод `getRequestDispatcher(String path)` - реализованный из интерфейса `ServletRequest`, который возвращает объект `RequestDispatcher`, у которого в свою очередь есть: `public void forward(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response);`

Подробнее по работе данных методов и классов можно прочесть тут:

1) http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)

2)

[http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse))